# CCSDK Web, Get Colors in a Library

Tags: adobecreativesdk

Does anyone know how to get colors that are stored in a CC Library?  For example, I can see the colors exist, but there is no way to select them from the asset browser.  The colors are greyed out and not selectable.  Additionally, I would even prefer a means of API access, to list all the colors in given library/libraries if that is possible.  Screenshot for reference regarding the colors in an asset browser (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhPmq8rPJiUghLhLJJOS85fleFj1Fg).

Additionally, I have tried some of the code below in the console once the CreatedSDK has been initialized/Authenticated, but all return undefined or error.

```
AdobeCreativeSDK.API.Libraries.getLibraries();
AdobeCreativeSDK.API.Libraries.getLibraries({});
AdobeCreativeSDK.API.Libraries.getLibrary();
AdobeCreativeSDK.API.Libraries.getLibrary({id:'<LibraryIDHere>'}, function(response){console.log(response)});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to get my colors out programmatically too.

Comment: No luck yet. I think remember seeing a new Adobe sdk marketed for early 2018 but it hasn't been released yet.